# Android SQLite select with like

Tags: android, sqlite, t-sql, select

I'm working sqlite. I wrote some code which can to select some datas with like in table 
this is a part my source

```
String[] args = new String[1];
args[0] = "%" + personalid + "%";
Cursor friendLike = db
        .rawQuery(
                "select * from LoanList  WHERE PersonID like ?",
                args);


SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
//Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

System.out.println("Cursor Count = " + friendLike.getCount());
```

I can select with PersonID from loan list, but now I want to select(with like) with two parameters. with PersonID and for example personage
just, I want to add second parameter in select.
How?

Comment: Add a **?** to the query and a value to the args array.

Comment: i tryed but  how i can wrote in rawQuery ? @ Der Golem

Comment: I added an answer to show you how to do that correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a second **?** and a second argument to the array:

```
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

String[] args = new String[]{"Some Value", "%" + personalid + "%"};
Cursor friendLike =
    db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM LoanList  WHERE SomeField = ? AND PersonID Like ?", args);
```

SomeField is your other search field.

The placeholders (**?**) respect the bound parameter list (your args array) order.